# Python can't find a directory that exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have a folder structure that looks like this

```
.  
├── requirements.txt  
├── resources  
│   ├── img  
│   │   └── chessboard  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153053.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153058.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153101.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153103.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153106.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153108.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153112.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153116.jpg    
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153118.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153123.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153126.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153129.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153131.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153134.jpg  
│   │       ├── 2022-02-01-153136.jpg  
│   │       └── 2022-02-01-153137.jpg  
└──scripts  
    └── calibrate.py
```

and `calibrate.py` looks like this

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

# Parameters
IMAGES_DIR = os.path.join("..", "resources", "img", "chessboard")
IMAGES_FORMAT = ".jpg"
SQUARE_SIZE = 2.9  # cm
# Count lines not boxes
WIDTH = 6
HEIGHT = 7


def calibrate_chessboard(dir_path, image_format, square_size, width, height):
    """Calibrate a camera using chessboard images."""
    images = glob(f"{dir_path}/*.{image_format}")

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

    objp = np.zeros((height * width, 3), np.float32)
    objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:width, 0:height].T.reshape(-1, 2)
    objp = objp * square_size

    objpoints = []  # 3d point in real world space
    imgpoints = []  # 2d points in image plane.

    # Iterate through all images
    for file in images:
        img = cv2.imread(str(file))
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # Find the chess board corners
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (width, height), None)

        # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
        if ret:
            objpoints.append(objp)

            corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
            imgpoints.append(corners2)

    # Calibrate camera
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(
        objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None
    )

    return [ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs]

# Calibrate
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = calibrate_chessboard(
    IMAGES_DIR, IMAGES_FORMAT, SQUARE_SIZE, WIDTH, HEIGHT
)
```

For some reason that I can't understand the line `images = glob(f"{dir_path}/*.{image_format}")` finds no files despite the path being correct, I even tried executing in both the root and the `scripts/` folder. The script is supposed to glob all the files in the directory and use them to find the camera distortion matrix

Comment: Your directory structure is *extremely* unclear

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that Python files do not _necessarily_ run from their current location. You could probably fix this by using `__file__` somewhere (which _is_ by definition the script location)

Comment: You already have a `.` in `IMAGES_FORMAT`, the extra one in the glob call might be throwing it off.

Comment: You're assuming that the _current directory_ is the directory where the script is located.  This is not necessarily true.

Comment: "For some reason that I can't understand" then that is why you should try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code. Test *all* your assumptions. You are sure the path is correct; but how about the string being passed to `glob`, for example?

Comment: As an aside, consider using [the `pathlib` standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) instead. It provides a nicer interface than `os` and `glob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a small potential issue in with your pathing / filetype.

```
images = glob(f"{dir_path}/*.{image_format}")
```

and

```
IMAGES_FORMAT = ".jpg"
```

These both include the `.` so you wont find any of your images since they only have a single dot. Try removing the dot from either `IMAGES_FORMAT = ".jpg"` or your other line.